Why is this library build now not executing the "jar" goal before "install"?
I'm working on a project that builds a library that we install in the maven repo.  When I just do "mvn install", the last two goals it executes are shown here:
[INFO] --- jar:3.4.1:jar (default-jar) @ soap-api-client ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\...\git\soap-api-client\target\soap-api-client-2.9.0.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- install:3.1.2:install (default-install) @ soap-api-client ---

This is what it's supposed to do.
The pom.xml currently uses "maven-dependency-plugin" to dump the classes from one dependency into "${project.build.outputDirectory}" (target/classes), and also uses the "transformer-maven-plugin" to perform the "javax->jakarta" transformation. It uses the "transform" goal, which I guess means it transforms everything in target/classes.
I have changed this to remove the dependency plugin, and changed the transformer plugin to use the "jar" goal instead, specifying the artifact I want transformed and where to write it to. I then use the "maven-antrun-plugin" to unzip the transformed artifact into "${project.build.testOutputDirectory}" (target/test-classes, I would think).  Note that this is functionally different from the previous, as it was previously extracting the classes into target/classes. This change is actually more correct, as those transformed classes are only required for tests.
This change works fine for the compile and test phases.  However, at the very end of the build, I see this:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:3.1.2:install (default-install) on project soap-api-client: The packaging plugin for project soap-api-client did not assign a file to the build artifact -> [Help 1]

I then looked earlier in the build output, and I realized that the "jar" goal, as shown earlier, is not executed.  It seems pretty likely that's the cause of the error, but I don't know why the changes I've made result in the "jar" plugin goal not being executed.
For some code, here is the "dependency" plugin, which is in the original code, but which I've removed in the new changes:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                            <groupId>...</groupId>
                            <artifactId>CommonOMS_220</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0.0</version>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

And here is what I've replaced that with:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.transformer</groupId>
    <artifactId>transformer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <attach>false</attach>
        <buildDirectory>${project.build.directory}/transformed</buildDirectory>
        <rules>
            <jakartaDefaults>true</jakartaDefaults>
        </rules>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>CommonOMS_220</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <artifact>
                    <groupId>...</groupId>
                    <artifactId>CommonOMS_220</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <type>jar</type>
                </artifact>
                <baseName>CommonOMS_220</baseName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>prepare</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <unzip src="${project.build.directory}/transformed/CommonOMS_220.jar" dest="${project.build.testOutputDirectory}"/>
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

